# Django STATIC_URL does not work, does not serve files

Tags: python, django

I have a company wordpress blog at `http://example.com` and Django application successfully deployed at `http://example.com/web`.

My application is a simple app (I still learn Django) where I would like to have a background for the 'welcome' pages (and other pages too).

I read in docs that I need to use `STATIC_URL` - so here's what I have and what I did:

1. My project structure:

[image]

2. Entires in `settings.py` file which are relevant for serving static files:

> ```
> STATIC_URL = '/web/static/'
> SETTINGS_PATH = os.path.dirname(__file__)
> PROJECT_PATH = os.path.join(SETTINGS_PATH, os.pardir)
> STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, "static"), )
> USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST = True
> FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME = '/web'
> SUB_SITE = "/web"
> ```

And here's the template file, `base.html` in which I would like to use `back.jpg` as webpage background image:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Simple Site
        {% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
    </head>
    <body background="/static/back.jpg" text="white"/>

                <div align="center">

        <h1>{% block head %}{% endblock %}</h1>
        {% block content %}{% endblock %}

                </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

However, I can't see the image. It's a production (not dev) app. How can I solve this?

Comment: And did you configure your server to serve anything from /web/static/?

Comment: Sorry, I've forgotten to mention, I'm using Apache 2.2

Comment: That doesn't tell us anything. Have you configured Apache to serve static files from that path?

Comment: I configured Apache as suggested by @Ewan

Comment: FWIW. If you are using Apache/mod_wsgi you shouldn't need to set ``FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME``. If not using mod_wsgi, what are you using, FASTCGI???

Comment: @Graham Dumpleton: What do YOU know about mod_wsgi? ;-)

Comment: Apparently I don't know that much as I still quite often get people that don't take any advice I give. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Your background is looking in the wrong place for the background image, you should use the [`static` template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#static)

```
<body background="{% static 'back.jpg' %}" text="white"/>
```

To use this, you need to load in static (preferably at the top of your template)

```
{% load static %}
```

Comment: Changed it as you suggested ang got: `TemplateSyntaxError at / Invalid block tag: 'static'`

Comment: Ok, added `{% load static %}` at the top of the page, error dissappeared, but still can't see the background

Comment: Check the file path (view source in browser), its either pointing to the wrong place or you haven't ran `collectstatic`

Comment: When browsing `http://example.com/web/static/back.jpg` I got `Internal Server Error`

Comment: It can't be the permissions issue, since I temporarly used `chmod 777 -R web/` and `chown -R www-data:www-data web/`

Comment: @yak - It sounds like you need to run `collectstatic`.. Please update your question with the error..

Answer (score 2):

Using whatever webserver (Apache or Nginx) you need to configure them to server your static files.

**Nginx**

Look at the [serving static content](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/serving-static-content/) section of the nginx resources.

```
location /web/static {
    root /path/to/example.com/static/;
}
```

**Apache**

Django has [good documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/) on deploying with Apache and `mod_wsgi` including how to [serve static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#serving-files).

```
Alias /web/static/ /path/to/example.com/static/

<Directory /path/to/mysite.com/static>
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: It didn't help, I will check out the docs, however, did almost everything the docs suggested with no success...